# How to take off title from wordpress page loop?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Below is my wordpress loop and i have tired to take-off the Page title but its not happning.
Please suggest me the correct loop.

```
<div class="single-full-width-container single-page-header-container">
  <header class="container">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="single-page-heading">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    <ul class="single-page-breadcrumbs">
      <?php
    if(function_exists('bcn_display') && !is_front_page())
        {
            bcn_display();
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <main role="main" class="shortcode-container span12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
          <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
          <div class="entry-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
          </div>
          <!-- .entry-content -->
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

I have tried with other loop without the "title" tag but its still coming at top.

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            //
            // Post Content here
            //
        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the `<title>` HTML tag, or `the_title()` that you pasted?

Comment: This is I know Check this Img i61.tinypic.com/wk5ycg.jpg I want to remove the title from default post.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="single-page-heading">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

Comment: This is I know Check this Img http://i61.tinypic.com/wk5ycg.jpg I want to remove the title from default post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not editing the proper file.

There is a line in your file:
`<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>`

This part is intended to import the `content-page.php` file as far as I know. Maybe this file puts the title on the top of the article. Try to edit that file if you find anything like that. If there is no `content-page.php` it falls back to import `content.php`.

(For more details check this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part )

If I'm right the part of the file you cited above makes no effect after the second appearance of this line:

`<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

Because the first appearance looped through the whole collection of the posts so the `have_posts()` function returns `false` after that. So the whole section until `<?php endwhile; ?>` (lines 22-33) is always skipped.

I hope I was right and could help you with your task :)